# Why adding subdivision surface modifier solid object like this and loop cut not adding?

Tags: modifiers

Why my object is solid like this after adding subdivision surface modifier? I am trying to add more loop cuts for refining but unable to add them on soiled positions.

I have tried adding more loop cuts and also merge vertex by distance I mean remove the doubles.

1st image is after and before applying the subdivision surface modifier and the 2nd image is after I tried adding more loop cuts and details into my mesh.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I have tried and make changes as you instructed. I tried to clean my topology but my result is not clean. Where I am wrong now? Also uploaded the updated file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The simple answer is that your topology is bad and you need to find better way to make your object

Comment: But if you actually don't care about your topology at all and still want easy solution to make this work then select all edges that need to be sharp and use Shift+E to make them purple, when they are purple, subdiv recognize them as those who need to stay sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should redo your topology:

- Simplify your shape, boolean the cylinder:

[image]

- Rework the topology, symmetrize:

[image]

- Bevel the edges:

[image]

- Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, shade smooth:

[image]

Edit: Here is a bevel from your current file. Also, before that, make sure the normals of your faces are correctly oriented, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: I tried to make my topology better several time but don't know what to do and how I do that. Now I am going to try this. Thank you!

Comment: How to add vertices after bolean the cylinder? In 2nd image as you showing.

Comment: use tools like knife (K to activate) or join vertices (J), dissolve edges (Ctrl X), etc...

Comment: I have tried and make chages as you instructed. I tried to clean my topology but my result is not clean. Where I am wrong now? Also uploaded the updated file. Please review the question.

Comment: you need to bevel the edges as seen in my third picture, select the edges and press Ctrl B in order to create these bevels. Maybe look for tutorials on the basics of modeling, your shape is a bit hard if you are a total beginner

Comment: I did bevel before adding the modifier.

Comment: I've checked your current file and the edges weren't bevelled, please see my edit

Comment: Can you suggest some tutorial. I have watched many tutorial this month, Started from the donut and then an anvil. Then udemy and then a robot from Ryan King Art youtube channel. Now I am on your youtube channel. Also subcribed. Can you suggest something from there or anywhere else?

Comment: There are a lot, I think Grant Abbitt has some pretty good tutorials, look for his beginners tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98FkRIbihyQ ... If you speak french, join us on the Discord I link in the description of my videos

Comment: I could make a tutorial from your question by the way, as the shape is interesting

Comment: Very well, I will be very thankful for that. Let me know if you do so. I am trying design a robot and this one is the bottom part.

Comment: well if I make a tutorial it will be basically what I explained here  ;)  simplify your topology, use boolean (or knife project tool), rearrange the topology, bevel, etc

Comment: That is what I don't uderstood. I did simplify my topology as I can, you can see in the file. Where I was wrong? Let me know that.

Comment: Ok perhaps I'll do a tuto on this  ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thankyou so much! I just saw the tutorial on your channel. Very very helpful.

Comment: oh ok I was wondering if I would do it in english as well, fine if you understood in french

Comment: I don't understand french, but subtitles works.

Answer (score 1):

To give more answers to my comment, Your first way should be to remove extensive vertices to make your mesh clean so that it can work in a less destructive way without using booleans...

If you actually don't care about topology then just select all of your sharp edges like me and press Shift+E and drag it to full pink till it is sharp like this:
[image]

Solution depends on your needs because with this you will still end up with some bad topology and it will be bad if you want to change it even more:
[image]

Comment: I tried to make my topology better several time but don't know what to do and how I do that. I want to make topology better. Thank you!